# How to get data from a SQL stored proc and write it to a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm having some trouble creating a method that can run a stored proc and save that data to a multi-dimensional array. In my below code I use the .ExecuteReader() instead of .ExecuteNonQuery() because I don't know if i'm going to be passing in a query or a stored proc so I thought that I would just leave it as is.

Here is my code for connecting to the database and then saving to an array (List). This works fine for me if my query/stored proc only returns one row of data, however it will stop working if I try to return multiple rows of data. I know I'm fairly close to getting something working but I just can't get this last section to work. Some of the things I tried to do was saving to a List< List< string>> but that kept giving me errors when I tried to save to it. I also tried to make two separate List< string> and then concatenate them together which unfortunately didn't work either.

```
public static List<string> CreateSqlConnection( string query, string sqlConn )
    {
        List<string> dataCollection = new List<string>();

        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection( sqlConn );
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand( query, myConn );
        SqlDataReader reader;

        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while ( reader.Read() )
            {
                for ( int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++ )
                {
                    dataCollection.Add( Convert.ToString( reader[i] ) );
                }
            }

            myConn.Close();
            return dataCollection;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error ({0}): {1}", ex.Number, ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error ({0}): ", ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine( ex.StackTrace );
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            myConn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I have very little experience with writing multidimensional arrays but with some help from google I wrote something up that reads from a file and will save to a multi-dimensional array, that I can use later for parsing.

```
public void ArrayTest(int rowsInArray, int columnsInArray)
    {
        string input = File.ReadAllText(@"File Name to read from"); // Removed temporarily the file name.
        int i = 0, j = 0;

        string[,] result = new string[rowsInArray, columnsInArray];
        foreach (var row in input.Split('\n'))
        {
            j = 0;
            foreach (var column in row.Trim().Split(','))
            {
                result[i, j] = column.Trim();
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Also, I read that Jagged array's are better to use for efficiency's sake but I wasn't able to get a Jagged array to be able to take in a "dynamic" size of both rows and columns.

Any help for creating something like this would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention I tried saving to a DataTable my results but I wasn't able to use that for the way that i'm planning on using the data afterwards.

Comment: In my second paragraph I mentioned that I tried to do a List< List< String>> which unfortunately did not work the way that I wanted it to.

Comment: Your code is currently flattening your result set into a single list, if you want a `List<List<string>>` each iteration of the outer `while` loop will need to create a new `List<string>`, add each `reader[i]` element to it, and add the resultant list to the "main" `List<List<string>>`.

Comment: I had something similar except I was using a for loop and iterating through the row.FieldCount(). I will try doing this way instead.

Comment: FYI, the difference between `ExecuteReader` and `ExecuteNonQuery` is *not* the explicit command(s) you are executing, but whether or not you expect it to return a Dataset or not.  If you are executing a stored procedure that you expect will return a dataset, then you should probably use `ExecuteReader` or you will not be able to read it.

Comment: Ah ok, Thank you. I did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (snipping out some stuff)

```
List<List<string>> dataCollection = new List<string>();
List<string> rowCollection;

while ( reader.Read() )
{
    rowCollection = new List<string>();
    for ( int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++ )
    {
        rowCollection.Add( Convert.ToString( reader[i] ) );
    }
    dataCollection.add(rowCollection);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I didn't think about doing something like this. I will try this out shortly and hopefully this works the way I'm hoping it will..

Comment: Thank you so much this worked exactly how I wanted it to work! Very much appreciated your help! Marked your answer as the correct answer.